# TYPO3 Extbase Localization, follow relations from parent?

Tags: php, localization, typo3, extbase

I've been researching and testing TYPO3's localization system for extensions and I'm very confused. My main problem with it is described below, in the section named `TYPO3 v9 and higher` in the [Localizing and internationalizing an extension](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/10.4/en-us/9-CrosscuttingConcerns/1-localizing-and-internationalizing-an-extension.html)
 documentation:

> Setting Typo3QuerySettings->languageOverlayMode to true makes Extbase fetch records from default language and overlay them with translated values [...] For relations, Extbase reads relations from a translated record (so it’s not possible to inherit a field value from translation source) and then passes the related records through $pageRepository->getRecordOverlay().

Why does it work like this instead of just **following the relations of the default record** (`sys_lang_uid` = 0)? Since it works this way, e.g. if you want to translate your website to 4 languages you have to maintain the same database relationships 4 times (including MM records). For example, for my Blog, if someone using it in German changes one Article and links it to another one, this change is only done for the German website, not the English one.

What I'm describing would be akin to how [connected mode for Localized content works](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-frontendlocalization/10.4/en-us/LocalizedContent/Index.html), you only want the translated records for the translated fields, everything elese (including relations) are taken from the default one. Is there any way of making it follow the relations of the default record for all languages?

Thanks a lot in advance

Here is the `languages` part of my site config:

```yaml
languages:
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    languageId: 0
    base: /
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_US.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: English
    hreflang: en-US
    direction: ltr
    flag: en-us-gb
    solr_core_read: core_en
  -
    title: German
    enabled: true
    languageId: 1
    base: /de/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: German
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ltr
    flag: de
    solr_core_read: core_de
    websiteTitle: ''
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
  -
    title: Spanish
    enabled: true
    base: /es/
    typo3Language: es
    locale: es_ES.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: es
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: Spanish
    hreflang: es-ES
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: es
    solr_core_read: ''
    languageId: 3
```

Comment: Can you check if [Respect resolved language overlay mode in Extbase](https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/66694) makes a difference?

Comment: @MathiasBrodala thanks a lot for answering. I guess the part that says:

'Additionally the language overlay mode is now forwarded to queries used to fetch relations leading to a really consistent and predictable language overlay behavior.'

is what would be interesting for what I was talking about. But I've tried applying the diff and the overlay mode works the same as before, the relationships are taken from the translated records instead of the default one. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, just wanted to be sure that this is ruled out. Can you add your site config to your post?

Comment: @MathiasBrodala Yes, this is it: https://paste.debian.net/1239082/
But what I'm asking is not exactly a bug, I just want to know if there's a way for the relations to be taken from the default (parent) record instead of the translated ones. I really don't see how this default behavior (relations being taken for each translated record) make sense.

Comment: I asked exactly for the languages of your site config for this reason. Actually the default behavior is to fetch relations from the default language and then do overlays. Only if you use a different language fallback type, you can change this. But you seem to be using `strict` here which normally doesn't show this behavior ...

Comment: @MathiasBrodala I've been reading all the documentation and testing for days and I'm still very confused.

Is this: 'the default behavior is to fetch relations from the default language and then do overlays' really true? Because according to _Localizing and internationalizing an extension_, `languageOverlayMode`: **For relations, Extbase reads relations from a translated record (so it’s not possible to inherit a field value from translation source)**

But there's indeed a way?

Comment: @MathiasBrodala I've tried with both `$query->setQuerySettings($settings->setLanguageOverlayMode(true/false));` , in Repository methods for show/list actions, and relations are always those of the translated record, not the default.

Sorry for the insistence but It would make everything so easy if that would be possible to be done!

Comment: Can you add a snippet of your field TCA? You may be able to solve this using `'l10n_mode' => 'exclude'` which will automatically copy relation updates to translations. But yes, I'd need to have a deeper look at the overlay behavior for relations.

Comment: @MathiasBrodala Yep, I also took a look at those TCA config options and they seem to work correctly for this use case! Regardless there's still a pretty severe problem with this approach which can be seen in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72055735/typo3-updating-non-default-language-records-with-exclude-fields
I still have to figure out how to solve this

Comment: This unanswered question seems being related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72075686/fallbacktype-free-brakes-translation-of-sys-categories