# TYPO3 Updating non-default-language records with exclude fields

Tags: localization, typo3, extbase

I have my site in both English and German. For my Extbase records, I configure all the fields with:

```
  'l10n_mode' => 'exclude',
  'l10n_display' => 'defaultAsReadonly',
```

except those `input` and `text` fields which contain text that I want to translate. This works as expected at a lower (TCA) level: If I want to change any of the excluded fields I change it in the English (default) record and the change is also reflected in the German record.

But I have a big problem in the frontend, in the Controller Update actions: when I'm visiting my website in German, and I update a German record changing one of the excluded fields, this change is only done for the German record and doesn't get reflected in the English record. Moreover, if I then change anything in the record through the backend, this change I made to the German record's field gets overwritten by the English record's value and therefore lost.

Is there any way to solve this kind of situations in an idiomatic manner for TYPO3's Extbase?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I'd try to adjust those things on user-level (including user-groups) for the backend.

Comment: @David Thanks for answering, but I fail to see how this could be solved by any type of user{,group} setting. Could you please elaborate more on what you had in mind? Because this issue has to do with the Edit actions on non-default translated records with fields configured with `'l10n_mode' => 'exclude'`, I don't see how we're supposed to manage this case in TYPO3.

Comment: In a "Backend usergroup" on the tab "Access Lists" exists the setting "Allowed excludefields". Included by default is the option for "tt_content.sys_language_uid". Missing fields like "l10n_mode" or "l10n_display" related to that setting you could add by changing the fields in TCA by adding the option "[field].exclude=1". The options on the tab "Explicitly allow/deny field values" and "Limit to languages" offer further settings that could be relevant. Furthermore you could add "TSconfig" on the tab "Options".

Comment: @David Sorry but I don't understand. I'm talking at an Extbase level, not Backend. The problem I described is when the record gets edited in a Edit action of the Controller, so in the Frontend.

Comment: Dynamic changes of TCA are not reflected by TYPO3 until you clear the cache either for a page or the whole site. So if you want to achieve that effect without clearing the cache you've to assure that the TCA is saved / cached including the conditions and resulting changes in configuration. Not sure if that applies to your situation.

Comment: In Fluid you can acquire the record of the original language (sys_language_uid=0)  from a translation somehow but it's not possible there to get all the translated records from the original record. As you have only 2 languages a workaround might be possible though. A solution in Extbase would be to circumvent the default database-layer and just use DBAL directly. Like that you're free if you want to provide both languages in different Fluid-variables or just, as common, the correct values in one variable.

Comment: If you use DBAL directly you have to include an own version of all or most used Repository-methods in your Repository probably.