# fallbackType: free brakes translation of sys_categories

Tags: typo3, tx-news

"fallbackType: free" in the config.yaml seems not to work with displaying sys_categories in the frontend. Backend works as expected, but in the frontend default and foreign language are shown together.

My news template shows a list of categories to filter news by categories. With "fallbackType: strict" this works fine, but not with "fallbackType: free": In the default language the list is shown in the default language, as expected. But in the foreign language we get a list of all translated categories and additional all categories in the default language. In single view of news i get the category list bound to the news always in the default language, never translated.

Is this a feature or a bug? How can i work around? I need "fallbackType: free" because my client wants to publish news in the foreign language without a news in the default language. So i can't simply switch back to "fallbackType: strict".

(TYPO3 10.4)

Thanks!

Comment: This question describes some problems (and reasons) related to translations in TYPO3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72009879/typo3-extbase-localization-follow-relations-from-parent

Comment: Hi David, this problem is not discussed there.

Comment: Hi @lisardo, ok this might be still helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72151852/1019850 or this: https://github.com/georgringer/extbase_with_no_l10n_parent.
Once I wrote an own extension related to some language problems, but that would need perhaps some more work: https://github.com/DavidBruchmann/wdb_language_fallback.
Sorry I never dig too much in your problem you've to check if the links are applying at all to your problem.

Comment: The Extension from Georg could be a solution to my problem ... Thanks David! I will give it a try.