# TYPO3 language handling: Problems with free mode when fallbackType=fallback

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

This is my language configuration for my TYPO3 v10 site in site configuration:

```
fallbackType: fallback
fallbacks: '0'
```

This works as expected for pages in "Connected Mode". But when an editor creates a page in "Free Mode", the translated page displays in FE both the translated and the default content elements. I do not understand why the content elements from default language are shown here. Is this a bug of TYPO3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a TYPO3 bug: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/90261

There's an extension which fixes this: https://github.com/qbus-agentur/typo3-dynamic-language-mode

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this a bug. Probably related to https://forge.typo3.org/issues/88965#change-442588 (please add a comment there to bring more focus on this)

But some things should be clearified here anyway:

- `fallbackType` in site configuration is independent from the translation strategy (mode) used in backend
- `fallbackType` and the used translation mode in backend are related to contents not to pages
- the actual expected behaviour here would be that only contents from the default language are displayed because the way `fallbackType: fallback` works is: load all contents from default language and then overlay them with translations
  https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/AddLanguages.html#fallbacktype

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found another bug which describes my problems: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/90261